# List of commands to determine what languages an environment supports?

Tags: shell, ssh, scripting, environment

I'm wondering if anyone has a large list of commands that determine whether certain programming languages are supported on an environment.

For example, a small list might be

```
python3 --version
ruby --version
rustc --version
```

I'm looking for something that covers the majority of popular programming languages.

For context, I'm taking a class that allows programs to be written in "any language the environment supports" on the universities server that we ssh into.

Comment: Is this something you really need to automate? You more than likely already have something you *want* to use in mind, and you can probably install it in your home directory if it's not already pre-installed.

Comment: I'm guessing the point is to find an especially obscure supported language and write in that. Typical examples being `m4`, `dc`, `sed` or postscript.

Comment: I have to use a language that is supported by the existing environment. Yes, I have some thoughts of what I want to use, but it might be nice to see some languages that I hadn't thought of. I am a student after all.